# Why isn't my tap recognised?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I've created a small sample project with a nib containing an image view. In my view controller code, I've added a gesture recogniser to the image view to detect taps. But it never calls the handler method.

Here's the header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TapExperimentViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;

@end
```

And here's the implementation file:

```
#import "TapExperimentViewController.h"

@implementation TapExperimentViewController

@synthesize imageView;

- (void)dealloc {
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.imageView = nil;
}

- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"tap");
    }
}

@end
```

I've made sure that the outlet is connected. Why isn't handleTap: being called when I touch the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not worked with gestures myself but I know that [`UIImageView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s do not enable user interaction by default.

> New image view objects are configured
>   to disregard user events by default.
>   If you want to handle events in a
>   custom subclass of UIImageView, you
>   must explicitly change the value of
>   the userInteractionEnabled property to
>   YES after initializing the object.

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting. Hang on, let me give it a go.

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I will accept as soon as the Stack Overflow timer lets me.

Comment: You are welcome. This value can also be set in Interface Builder. There is section under view called Interaction.